# $g:x\rightarrow \left |2x-3 \right |-4$ for $-2 \leq x \leq k$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

A function $g$ is defined by $g:x\rightarrow \left |2x-3  \right |-4$ for $-2 \leq x \leq k$.

Find the range of $g$ and state the largest value of $k$ for which $g$ has an inverse.

My attempt,

The range of $g(x) \geq-4$. How to find $k$? Is my range correct?

Comment: The range should of course also depend on $k$, i.e., there will be an upper bound on $g(x)$ as well. You can find $k$ by making sure that $2x-3$ stays negative: As soon as it becomes positive, the magnitude operator becomes non-injective.

Answer (score 1):

For such exercises it is very useful to draw a picture: [image]

Keep the left point fixed at $x=-2$, and move the right point $x=k$. You need to deal with several cases to find the range of $g$. However it should be clear from the graph that $-2 \leq k \leq 3/2$ is the only range of values for which $g$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

We have the function $g$ which we can see to be decreasing in the interval $x \in \left[-2, \frac{3}{2}\right]$ and increasing for $x > \frac{3}{2}$.

Now, whilst you are correct that $g(x) \geq -4$, you still need to identify an upper bound that depends on $k$. If $k < 5$ then you can see that the upper bound on $g$ is trivially $3$. So that $-4 \leq g \leq 3$ is the required range. If $k>5$, then the upper bound becomes $|2k-3|-4$ so the range in that case is $-4 \leq g \leq |2k-3|-4$.

Since the only thing you can control is the upper bound of $g$ by choosing a suitable $k$, you want to bring down the $k$ to force the function to be injective or amenable to the "horizontal line test" to do this, you need $2x-3$ to be negative and hence the largest $k$ you can choose is $k = \frac{3}{2}$.